# Mongodb - increasing performance using compound index when pagination

Tags: mongodb, indexing, compound-index

I'm newbie to mongodb and I need help about increasing performance for queries using compound indexes.

I am using pagination using "_id" field. Query:

```
db.data.find( {"$or": [ { "cat": "5" }, {"cat": "6" } ] }, {"style": "3"}, 
              {"area": "London"}, {"_id": {"$lt": 103}).sort( { "_id": 1 } ).limit(30)
```

`style` and `area` can be optional so these are also possible.

```
db.data.find( {"$or": [ { "cat": "5" }, {"cat": "6" } ] },  
              {"area": "London"}, {"_id": {"$lt": 103}).sort( { "_id": 1 } ).limit(30)

db.data.find( {"$or": [ { "cat": "5" }, {"cat": "6" } ] }, {"style": "3"}, 
              {"_id": {"$lt": 103}).sort( { "_id": 1 } ).limit(30)

db.data.find( {"$or": [ { "cat": "5" }, {"cat": "6" } ] }, 
              {"_id": {"$lt": 103}).sort( { "_id": 1 } ).limit(30)
```

Will these queries be ok with this compound index, or do I need more additional index?

```
{ "cat": 1, "style": 1, "area": 1, "_id": 1 }
```

**Edit**

I'm not sure which of these index would be efficient for queries.

```
{ "cat": 1, "style": 1, "area": 1, "_id": 1 } or
{ "_id": 1, "cat": 1, "style": 1, "area": 1 }
```

Number of styles: 16

Number of Areas: 50

Number of id: 10 million

Comment: use {  "_id": 1, "cat": 1, "style": 1, "area": 1 }

Comment: @Disposer Can you please explain why "_id" has to be first field in index?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
{ "_id": 1, "cat": 1, "style": 1, "area": 1 }
```

ObjectId has this structure:

```
0 1 2 3   | 4 5 6   | 7 8 | 9 10 11
Timestamp | Machine | PID | Increment
```

because the `timestamp` comes first in above structure, it will sort in roughly
insertion order.

When id came first in index, it will reduce your looking objects.

Comment: As per mongodb documentation, the query which only includes _id, cat and area will be less efficient than index {"_id", "cat", "area"}. Is it better to create this another compound index?

Comment: And will it automatically fetch indexes from this new index for queries with only _id, cat, area?

Comment: if you use { "_id": 1, "cat": 1, "style": 1, "area": 1 } but in your query you are not using "area", the index works properly and efficient, but if you are not using "style" in query, index will not work efficiently

Comment: Yes, so better to create new index {"_id":1, "cat":1, "area":1}? and all good?

Comment: I believe you find your answer in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

Comment: I think you're wrong. _id has to be last component. Please see here http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/product-catalog/ Note: The final component of the index is the sort field. This allows MongoDB to traverse the index in the sorted order to preclude a slow in-memory sort.

Comment: In your case, you wanna sort by id. id usually sorted physically. I believe it should be your first item to index. use find(..).explain() and look which index is best for you (by number of scannedObjects) and put the result in your post if its possible.